# MySQL Math on "join" function

Tags: php, mysql

Not too sure how to explain this, but, basically I have two tables, and I need to do some math on their values. I am having issues with anything other than addition (which it does automatically).

This is the MySQL statement that I am using.

```
select snippet_id, count(snippet_id) as cnt
from snippets_likes join snippets_engagement on snippet_id = snippets_engagement.snip_id
group by snippet_id
order by cnt desc
```

This statements pulls the total number of likes + engagements.

However, I want to have it equal likes + ( engagements/1000 ).

Table construction

```
CREATE TABLE  `IOTunes`.`snippets_engagement` (
  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `snip_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `artist_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `snip_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `engagement_type` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6694 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE  `IOTunes`.`snippets_likes` (
  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `snippet_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `artist_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `snippet_like` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=197 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I have tried so many different formulas, but, cannot get this to work. Any pointers?

Comment: show your 'non-functioning' queries...

Comment: I'm guessing that actually pulls the # of likes X the # of engagements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this statement:

```
SELECT snippet_id, SUM(cnt) AS cnt
FROM (
   SELECT snippet_id, COUNT(1) AS cnt
   FROM snippets_likes 
   GROUP BY snippet_id
   UNION
   SELECT snippet_id, COUNT(1)/1000 AS cnt
   FROM snippets_engagement 
   GROUP BY snippet_id
) AS subQ
GROUP BY snippet_id
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

or if you insist on a join...

```
select sl.snippet_id, count(DISTINCT sl.ID) + count(DISTINCT se.ID)/1000 as cnt
from snippets_likes AS sl join snippets_engagement AS se 
on sl.snippet_id = se.snip_id
group by snippet_id
order by cnt desc
```

*I wouldn't recommend the join though, you'll only get values for "snippets" that have at least one "like" and one "engagement".*

Comment: I forgot to mention, that's exactly what I want. It must have one of both. ^_^

Nonetheless, it says snippet_id field does not exist. I'm trying to sort that out now! Thanks so much for the fast response! :D

Comment: It's working now! :)) You are super awesome, thanks!

Comment: Ah, I see, I used `snippet_id` instead of `snip_id` on the `snippet_engagement` portion.

Comment: ^_^ -- I hate that it won't let me upvote your answer :(

Comment: I am pretty sure you can mark it as the answer... though I've never actually asked a question, so I couldn't tell you how to do that. lol